# Uncommon letters not showing up correctly

Tags: php, character

I am using an API and taking a JSON array and converting it to a PHP array.  Everything is working fine, except for some special letters. For example, a user's name is

zâck

and when I test the call on the API's website it shows up like it should.  However, when I try to view it on my website, I get this:

zÃ¢ck

is there any way to make it show up properly on my website?

Comment: You have a character encoding issue.

Comment: What is the character set of every document that touches this variable

Comment: @ohgodwhy im not actually sure...the page I'm testing this on just has raw php code on it and no html.

Comment: Can you encode the string as UTF-8 before you print it to the stdout? Honestly, we need to see the code at this point.

Comment: `json_decode()` requires UTF-8 input. What is the charset of the response to your API request?

Comment: @ohgodwhy I added `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to the top of the PHP page and it seemed to work.